# How to Execute a Bash Script from PowerShell Core in Linux

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, powershell-core

I have a bash script `foo.sh` and I want to execute it with some arguments `--bar` from PowerShell Core. This doesn't work:

```
./foo.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a & operator

```
& "./foo.sh"
```

Or execute it using bash

```
& bash "./foo.sh"
```

Comment: It turns out you can also just do `./foo.sh`.

Comment: Using `& "./foo.sh"` or `./foo.sh` just opens foo.sh in the text editor on my system. To actually run the script I had to use: `& bash "./foo.sh"`